# Why does the STL reverse algorithm not work as I expect?

Tags: c++, stl-algorithm

Try to reverse a part of a vector:

```
vector<int> nums{1,2,3};
std::reverse(nums.begin(), nums.end()); //LINE1
std::reverse(nums.begin(), (nums.begin() + 1)); //LINE2
std::reverse((nums.begin() + 2), nums.end()); //LINE3
```

After LINE1, nums{3,2,1}

After LINE2 and LINE3, no change.

Expected: nums{2,3,1}

Comment: Those are half-open ranges.

Comment: Both LINE2 and LINE3 reverse ranges that contain only *one* element. Expectedly, reversing only one element does nothing.

Comment: Remember end() returns an iterator after the last element. 'std::reverse' takes an iterator AFTER the last element to reverse,not the last one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation for `std::reverse`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/reverse/):

> **Reverse range**
>
> Reverses the order of the elements in the range **[first,last)**.

Note the half-open range.

So, assuming you have three elements (range [0;2]):

**1)** `std::reverse(nums.begin(), (nums.begin() + 1));`

This operates on range [0; 0+1) -> [0; 1) -> [0;0] (it's an open range, so the closing boundary is not included itself).

**2)** `std::reverse((nums.begin() + 2), nums.end());`

Here, you got it wrong anyway, regarding ranges `reverse` operate on. `begin() + 2` means last element in your case, while `end()` is... end. So this line is meaningless and does nothing.